# Diskless client doesnt boot. Does anybody still use diskless clients?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, pxe

I have a class of machines on my network that should not have a harddisk (of any kind). They boot diskless and are very useful to me like that. (e.g. I need to be able to turn them off at any moment, no notice to flush everything to disk. Yes, modern filesystems often handle this correctly, but I want to be extra sure).

Soo.... PXE, bootp/dhcp, get kernel info, TFTP the kernel, initram, mount NFS root and off we go!

This has worked for decades. But now on Ubuntu 20.04, it seems the DHCP server will tell the booting client: "Go get your kernel from me: 127.0.1.1", so the client ends up sending IP packets to the TFTP server at 127.0.1.1.....  Those don't end up at the tftp server on my server....

So... Two options; I've copied over some old configuration file that used to work with previous LTS Ubuntu versions and that specifies something "funny" or something changed in the code.

My analysis is that DHCP is telling the client to use this IP address... but the DHCP response is too big for me to quickly analyse.

As this is still happening and I can't easily get it to work, Either nobody is still using this setup or I'm doing something wrong....

Comment: I don't use a TFTP client, but I understand the concept. What have you tried? E.g., replacing the server name by its IP address, using the `nextserver` parameter, etc. Please add the relevant lines of `dhcpd.conf` to your question.

Comment: Jos, I think you're on to something! The 127.0.1.1 ip address is listed with the server's name in /etc/hosts on the server. The DHCP server is using /etc/hosts to resolve its own hostname. I've added the server's own IP address with the name in /etc/hosts. I'm pretty confident that this will help. Everything clicks into place.